# How spark streaming application works when it fails?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I started learning about spark streaming applications with kinesis. I got a case where our spark streaming application fails, it restarts but the issue is, when it restarts, it tries to process more amount of messages than it can process and fails again. So,

1. Is there any way, we can limit the amount of data a spark streaming application can process in terms of bytes?
2. Any let say, if a spark streaming application fails and remains down for 1 or 2 hours, and the InitialPositionInStream is set to **TRIM_HORIZON**, so when it restarts, it will start from the last messages processed in kinesis stream, but since there is live ingestion going on in kinesis then how the spark streaming application works to process this 1 or 2 hours of data present in kinesis and the live data which is getting ingested in kinesis?

PS - The spark streaming is running in EMR and the batch size is set to 15 secs, and the kinesis CheckPointInterval is set to 60 secs, after every 60 secs it writes the processed data details in DynamoDB.

If my question is/are unclear or you need any more informations for answering my questions, do let me know.

**spark-streaming-kinesis**

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are trying to read the data from message queues like kafka or event hub.
If thats the case, when ever spark streaming application goes down, it will try to process the data from the offset it left before getting failed.

By the time, you restart the job - it would have accumulated more data and it will try to process all backlog data and it will fail either by Out of Memory or executors getting lost.

To prevent that, you can use something like "maxOffsetsPerTrigger" configuration which will create a back pressuring mechanism there by preventing the job from reading all data at once. It will stream line the data pull and processing.

More details can be found here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

From official docs

> Rate limit on maximum number of offsets processed per trigger
> interval. The specified total number of offsets will be proportionally
> split across topicPartitions of different volume.

Example to set max offsets per trigger

```
 val df = spark
    .read
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1")
    .option("subscribe", "topicName")
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
    .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", "10000")
    .load()
```

To process the backfills as soon as possible and catch up with real time data, you may need to scale up your infra accordingly.

May be some sort of auto scaling might help in this case.
After processing the backlogged data, your job will scale down automatically.
https://emr-etl.workshop.aws/auto_scale/00-setup.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But The solution which you said, will take work for AWS Kinesis? Because I tried searching it for Kinesis but not able to find that.

Comment: Yes, it should work for Kinesis as well. Irrespective of the message queue, you can use checkpoint logic from spark.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/streaming-kinesis-integration.html - should help you with kinesis integration with spark